# What does 少々疲れます mean in this case?

Tags: meaning

I was replying a message with question with an example about what I think she was wrong and she replied this:

間違い探しでもしてらっしゃるのでしょうか？少々疲れます。

Does it sound like I asked to much in the reply, or offended her, or annoyed her? Does she mean she was tired of answering me?

Or she means she had written the previous message wrong since she was tired? (But she didn't use past tense with 疲れます)

Comment: In case you have not noticed (and I do not think you have), 「少々」, in this context and situation, would actually  mean "fairly" or even "very much".

Answer (score 5):

I would say she's pretty irked. The super polite language like 〜らっしゃる in particular makes it sound pointed to me (though if she happens to always speak like that I guess it might be okay, but I'd doubt that).

少々疲れます means "I'm starting to get a little tired/exhausted.", with the conversation (which she called "間違い探し") being the implied cause/reason.

Comment: By "tired", do you mean literally or figuratively? I thought 疲れる always meant literally tired, and 飽きる always meant figuratively tired.

Comment: Literally. That parenthetical was misleading, wasn't it. Will fix.

Comment: No idea without seeing the rest of the conversation, but probably the last reply.

Comment: No, that's not what the first sentence means. It means something like "Would you happen to be playing a game of 'find the mistake'?" (excuse poor translation of 間違い探し).

Comment: To put it in other words: isn't the polite form sufficient to unanimously attribute 間違い探し to the actions of OP?

Comment: It is sufficient. It is definitely the actions of the OP, the only ambiguity is if it was the last thing they said or multiple previous things they've said.

Comment: So how about "she's getting tired with the conversation, because (implied) of your conduct which she likened to 間違い探し"

Answer (score 2):

[間違]{ま・ちが}い[探]{さが}し is a name of game, which is called "[Spot the difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference)" or something like that in English. [This pdf](http://happylilac.net/machi-kodomonohiparty-02.pdf) is an example of 間違い探し for young children.

Using the game name 間違い探し, she mildly told that her topic and your topic were different. She didn't really wonder whether you were playing 間違い探し game. 「間違い探しでもしてらっしゃるのでしょうか？」 implies that "What you're doing, like finding differences or mistakes, is off-topic. Why don't you talk about something on-topic?" I don't know if what you talked about was really off-topic, but, she seemed to think it was off-topic.

This 「少々疲れます」 implies "No more, please."

The whole line seems to imply "we've been talking to each other, but actually not communicating with each other. It seems meaningless. I talked to you, but you've been just caring about something else. That makes me tired."

Comment: @macraf I see, the first and the last parts were not about language. It's edited now. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @macraf I see. You want me to delete what you're not interested in. Now, I think it's the time for me to say it to you. 間違い探しでもしてらっしゃるのでしょうか？ 少々疲れます。Anyway, thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @macraf You're not helping me improve the answer this time. I know my answer is not perfect, so edit suggestions are always welcome. Since only "she" knows what she actually felt and meant, of course, I "guessed" it based on experience as a native Japanese speaker. She used the word 間違い探し as an indirect expression of what the OP did and 少々疲れます as a mild expression of what she felt in order to be nice, and the OP wonders what the straightforward meanings of those expressions are. So I answered the probable straightforward meanings.

Comment: @macraf If you think the parts of the answer are wrong or meaningless, why don't you write and tell the correct one or meaningful one in comment? Or give me a reasonable reason to delete them, please. It'll be helpful.